# Python: what is the point of mutability of objects?

Tags: python

I read everywhere the definition and the difference between mutable and immutable objects in Python. But why is this concept introduced, out of necessity? If not out of necessity, but say, practicality, what is the point of this? Why could not all objects be mutable?

Comment: If all objects are mutable, you couldn't safely use objects as keys in any kind of a set, dictionary, etc, because the hash values can change.

Comment: Frankly, I'd argue that having all objects be *immutable* is the better model, if you care about encouraging development of reliable software (explicit state management, &c) -- you don't need to worry about locking to control which thread can make changes to an object if your objects can't change. Take a look at how Clojure does it (outside the interop and single-threaded-performance-sensitive corner cases).

Comment: No language made in the last 20 years has mutable strings. Look into why. Better yet, go program in C and find out why.

Comment: That said, this isn't really a good StackOverflow question. From https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask -- "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face". There's no actual problem posed here, and the topic of discussion is broad enough that the question isn't amenable to a single canonical answer as such. See also [What is the rationale for closing "why?" questions on language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394/what-is-the-rationale-for-closing-why-questions-on-a-language-design)

Comment: Immutable objects are easier to reason about, not subject to unexpected side-effects (Are you sure that the function `foo(list_)` doesn't mutate its argument?), and neatly avoid many of the issues that plague concurrent programs.  Mutable objects are *much* faster, and more accurately model many real-world systems.

Comment: I'm very grateful for all the discussion and clarifications. I do not even know what a hash value is, so you can probably understand that I'm quite the novice. I also have to apologize, I did not know that a why-question was against policy. If I could be guided to rephrase the question, I would be very grateful - and I also imagine quite a few people wonder the same thing as I, but cannot find a good answer.

Comment: @Erosennin, ...if you follow the link above, you'll note that the question it references (which was closed here on StackOverflow) was moved to, and welcome at, [softwareengineering.se] StackExchange. Not saying this particular question will be welcome there -- would need to read that site's help center, which has its own on-topic and off-topic pages -- but it has a good chance.

Answer (score 3):

## Why mutability exists

Consider this example.

```
lst = [None] * 1000000

lst[999999] = True
```

If you couldn't mutate your list, you would have to build it back everytime you want to update it. It would be long.

## Why immutability exists

Now consider this other example.

```
my_script_version = (3, 2, 4) # 3.2.4

my_script_version[0] = 4 # TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Some things are not meant to be updated an immutable data types are good for these.

## And then there are dictionaries

Furthermore, Python relies a lot on `dict`. For an object to be a key in a dictionary, it must be immutable. Let's try to force Python to use a mutable object as a dictionary key to see what happens.

```
class MutableKey(list):
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple(self)) # We force Python to hash a list as if it were a tuple

key = MutableKey([])

d = {key: 1}
key.append(1)

d[MutableKey([])] # KeyError
d[MutableKey([1])] # KeyError
d[key] # KeyError
```

For an object to be a dictionary key, it must *always* hash to the same value and it must *always* compare the same way to other objects. Both of these conditions are false for mutable objects.

Comment: The "why mutability exists" side of this answer ignores recent advances in data structures. We have (today!) the ability to do updates to list-like immutable objects in amortized-constant-time performance -- O(log32n) -- and similarly bounded memory usage, and there are available language runtimes today that *do* take advantage of this.

Comment: See [Understanding Clojure's Persistent Vectors](https://hypirion.com/musings/understanding-persistent-vector-pt-1) for one such implementation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks! I definitely think you should add an answer regarding this as it's a good read! I will read through that and maybe update my answer once I did but for now I do not know enough on the subject.